Three.js is the object behind you not visible when you turn to face it?
When you turn the camera to the back side - looking at it frontally, the object disappears - stripes.
I don't understand how to fix it, live example.


const scene = new THREE.Scene()
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias : true});
renderer.setSize(divSize["width"], divSize["height"]);
renderer.sortObjects = false;

visualization.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, divSize["width"] / divSize["height"] , 0.1, null);

    const group = new THREE.Group();

    const sheetGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, length, 0);
    const sheetMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        map: sheetTexture,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        depthWrite: false,
        transparent: false, 
        opacity: 1,
        alphaTest: 0.1
    });

    const sheet = new THREE.Mesh(sheetGeometry, sheetMaterial);
    sheet.geometry.computeBoundingBox();

    pointsRight.push( new THREE.Vector3(x, bSheet.max.y, -50) );
    pointsRight.push( new THREE.Vector3(x, bSheet.min.y, -50) );

    let lineRightGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(pointsRight);
    let lineRight = new THREE.Line(lineRightGeometry, lineMaterial);

    group.add(lineRight);

